# How can I stop my iPad from ringing when my iPhone rings?

Tags: ios, ipad

Similar to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169577/how-do-i-stop-my-mac-from-ringing-when-i-get-a-phone-call-on-my-iphone), but my iPad is ringing, not my Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings > FaceTime and turn off "iPhone Cellular Calls" and your iPad won't ring any more.