# Stop iPhone from ringing on my Mac in Mojave

Tags: iphone, facetime

This was answered in 2015, but it's not working for me:

[How do I stop my Mac from ringing when I get a phone call on my iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169577/how-do-i-stop-my-mac-from-ringing-when-i-get-a-phone-call-on-my-iphone)

Following the instructions there and elsewhere, I've turned off "Calls from my iPhone" in Facetime, and "Calls on Other Devices" in Settings > Phone on my iPhone, but every time my phone rings, I also get a deafening ring on my Mac.

Comment: so which app is ringing ?

Comment: It shows up as a notification from FaceTime.

Comment: I've just updated to Mojave, and I'm having this issue too.

Comment: Not a solution but until I can come up with one, I've disconnected FaceTime from my Apple ID.

Comment: I've set my iPhone not to ring for numbers not in my contacts but they still ring through to my mac book.  Anyway to stop that?

Answer (score 2):

Open FaceTime.

Go to the Preferences menu

Disable the phone numbers that you don't want to ring through to your Mac.

Turn off "Calls from iPhone"