# How do I prevent ringing sound on my Macbook when receiving a call on my iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, ios, facetime

I know this question has been [asked before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169577/how-do-i-stop-my-mac-from-ringing-when-i-get-a-phone-call-on-my-iphone), but none of the answers work for me.

When I receive a call on my iPhone, my Macbook plays a ringing sound.  Strangely, there is no notification that appears, nor does anything appear in the Notification Center.

1. I have opened FaceTime on my Macbook and disabled iPhone Cellular Calls.
2. I have signed out of my Apple ID entirely in the FaceTime app on my Macbook.
3. On my iPhone I've disabled "Calls on Other Devices" in Settings > Cellular.
4. I've turned on "Do Not Disturb" on my Macbook.

I am using MacOS Catalina (10.15.3) and my iPhone is a Pro 11 Max (iOS 13.3).

Muting my Macbook works, of course, but this happens to me all the time when I'm on a video conference call (using Zoom or Google Hangouts) so I can't mute my Macbook because I can't hear my conference call (not to mention if this happens when I'm speaking everyone gets to hear my Macbook ring because I can't figure out how to shut it up).

Comment: Are you signed into iMessage on your Mac?

Comment: Yes, I use iMessage on my Mac all the time.

Comment: Try signing out and see if that solves the issue. That worked for me...